# Python Selenium - Webscrape Latitude and Longitude from the Maps

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to webscrape the latitude and longitude from the Maps in the [URL](https://www.thestorefront.com/listings/4673)

The HTML Script looks below,

```
<div class="map-container"><script>$(document).ready(function() {
  var $injector = angular.element(document.body).injector();
  var $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
  var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
  var sfMap = $compile('<div data-sf-map data-center="center" data-zoom="15" data-markers="markers" data-scrollwheel="false" data-zoom-level-change="14"></div>');
  var scope = $rootScope.$new();

  scope.center = {
    latitude: 40.7515022729943,
    longitude: -74.0071970200125
  };

  scope.markers = [{
    id: 4673,
    latitude: 40.7515022729943,
    longitude: -74.0071970200125
  }];

  var $el = sfMap(scope);
  $('.listing-map .map-wrapper .map-container').append($el);
});
```

I tried to use the option of Copy as XPath but it is not working for
this case. How to get the latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code to get latitude and longitude values:

```
import re

script = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="map-container"]/script').get_attribute('textContent')
latitude =  re.search('(?<=latitude: )-*\d+.\d+', script).group(0)
longitude = re.search('(?<=longitude: )-*\d+.\d+', script).group(0)
```